# If $p,q$ & $M$ are positive numbers & $q < 100,$ then the number obtained by increasing $M$ by $p$% & decreasing the result by $q$% exceeds $M \iff$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $p,q$ and $M$ are positive numbers and $q < 100,$ then the number obtained by increasing $M$ by $p$% and decreasing the result by $q$% exceeds $M \iff$

$(A)\ p > q \ (B) \ p > \frac{q}{100-q} \  (C) \ p > \frac{q}{1-q} \ (D) \ p > \frac{100q}{100+q} \ (E) \ p > \frac{100q}{100-q} $

I setup and inequailty and tried to reduce to any of the potential answers.

$
\begin{split}
(M(1+\frac{p}{100}))(1-\frac{q}{100}) & > M \\
(M+\frac{Mp}{100})(1-\frac{q}{100})   & > M \\
M-\frac{Mq}{100}+\frac{Mp}{100}-\frac{Mpq}{10000}  & > M \\
...
\end{split}$

After many attemps, I conclued with
$p > \frac{q(p+100)}{100}$ which really looks nothing like any of the choices above.
I haven't being able to eliminate any of the choices logically either so I'm afraid I'm out of ideas.

How can I go about sloving the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the choices is correct answer

You should factor by $M$ to exclude it in the begin:

$(1+p/100)(1-q/100)>1$

In the end you should get inequality, that does not contain $p$ on the right-hand side, because all the choices do not

You should leave all members containing $p$ to the left-hand side and move all remaining members to the right-hand side (changing their sign), then factor left-hand side by $p$ and divide both sides to make left-hand side just equal to $p$. Then you'll get correct answer

Comment: The answer is B?